# Using Regex to validate account numbers

Tags: regex

Could you please help me with a regular expression that would allow strings in several valid formats?

The formats are:

5digits dash 6digits

5digits dash 7digits

6digits dash 6digits

7digits dash 7digits

7digits dash 8 digits

I am asking this because I know almost nothing about regex.

Thanks.

Comment: By "5digits dash 6digits" you mean "00000-000000", "00000 - 000000", or "5digits dash 6digits"? It's not that obvious..

Comment: I meant "00000-000000"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to keep it simple to this regex:

```
/^\d{5,7}-\d{6,8}$/
```

Even though your specified formats can be validated by following regex:

```
^\d{5}-\d{6,7}|\d{7}-\d{7,8}|\d{6}-\d{6}$
```

but that won't be very maintainable for future changes.